# The 行 in 大唐女儿行 or 骊歌行

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the 行 in 大唐女儿行 or 骊歌行 (those are two variants of the title of a novel / tv series) mean? My dictionary is not helping me, as isn't the web :-|

Answer (score 9):

行 stands for [歌行体](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%AD%8C%E8%A1%8C), an ancient poem/folk song style, a type of [yuefu(乐府)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuefu) poem. Ancient poems written in this style are usually named x歌 or x行 (e.g., 琵琶行，长恨歌). Due to a looser constraint on format and length, these poems can have more narrative than many other forms of Chinese poems. The novel/tv seires you are asking about is likely using this title to invoke a sense of archaic beauty.

Answer (score 5):

> ode on 骊歌(a song of farewell) or ode to 大唐女儿

ode: a poem expressing the writer's thoughts and feelings about a particular person or subject, usually written to that person or subject

Comment: Is that xíng or háng? 行： 古诗的一种体裁：长歌行。

Comment: In the context of 古诗, always xíng

Answer (score 2):

I think 行 in 大唐女儿行 means ***journey, travel***. Metaphorically, it could mean what's going on about 大唐女儿.

Not sure about 骊歌行 though.

Answer (score 2):

I think 行 is the equivalent of "傳" or "記".

Here, the use of "行" in the show title is an imitation (copy-cat) of an ancient style of poem title such as "长歌行(李白)", "短歌行(陆机)", "燕歌行(曹丕)", "门有万里客行(曹植)"...etc.

.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry but their just some answers are correct. And i'm sure about it. '行'is a style of poem (a part of [樂府詩](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%A8%82%E5%BA%9C)), like '長干行' of 李白, '琵琶行' of 白居易.

I had learn this at high school, Chinese teacher will tell tou a same answer

Answer (score 1):

What does the 行 in 大唐女儿行 or 骊歌行 mean?

First and foremost, the word 行 has multifarious meanings, as you have no doubt found out from your rummage through the dictionaries?

As a verb, it usually means to travel, to go on a journey.

As a noun, it usually means personal behavior, conduct.

Thus, without any context marker, it could mean one of the following:-

(1)  A journey undertaken by 大唐女儿, or,

(2)  The personal behavior, conduct of 大唐女儿, as very often prepositions, semantic markers are silent in Chinese writings, especially in poetry or titles of literary works. So, the silent markers in this instance could be, (in brackets):-

大唐女儿(的)行(为)

A more contextual translation of the phrase could very well be "The antics of 大唐女儿", given that the story line of the TV play is probably of the comical genre, as modern "Sinowood" perceptions of the maidens of the Tang Dynasty era are one of coquettish, flirtatious antics.

As for 骊歌行, well, a literary translation would be like "An Ode to the Sojourner", as 骊 has something to do with a fine, handsome horse, and olden days travelers would need such a horse when going on a long, ("Romantic") journey.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what "大唐女儿行" is, seems it's the name of a TV series of "骊歌行". Regarding 骊歌行, I guess it's same with 长歌行, given "行" is at the end of whole world, it should be a noun, the dictionary said it's a Poetry genre.

BTW they are all read as xíng.

Answer (score -1):

All above answers are wrong
行 == Journey. period.

Comment: legend may also applies in this case,  referring to https://lyricstranslate.com/en/xi%C3%A1-k%C3%A8-x%C3%ADng-legend-knight.html